# in c#. how to serilialize and deserialize object with dictionary containing object of other classes inside it?

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization

I have object with members of different types like this:

```
public class Node
{
    public int itemID = -1; 
    public int counter = 1;  

    public Node parent = null;

    public List<Node> childs = new List<Node>();

    public Node nodeLink = null;
}
```

And I have  class tree

```
public class tree
{
    public List<int> headerList = null;

    public Dictionary<int, Node> mapItemNodes = new Dictionary<int, Node>();

    public Dictionary<int, Node> mapItemLastNode = new Dictionary<int, Node>();

    public Node root = new Node();
}
```

And I need your help to serialize and deserialize an object of the class tree that includes objects of the class node in its dictionaries.

Comment: What serializer or file format are you using?  `BinaryFormatter`?  XML?  JSON?  Something else?

Comment: I am a new user to C#, I tried alot but I didn't succeed to do serialization for the files you mention. so I can use any one could show results

Comment: my application is a desktop application. since my tree contains a lot of nodes I will be thankful if you know a fast solution for that. or provide me with an example for my problem

Comment: my aim is to write or store the content of the result tree after making run for the program and retreive it a again to the same objects of the program